# Socket on a Thread stops processing and locks the UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a standalone test application developed in c# (4.5). 
The application is primarily meant for sending some data to COM ports. The application accepts the data through the UI and the corresponding data is sent to respective COM ports.
For eg: Data from text box 1 goes to COM 1 on pressing a button, Data from Textbox 2 goes to COM 2 on pressing a different button etc.

Later I had to add a functionailty where a different set of data has to be accepted via Windows sockets and has to be sent to a different COM port other than above. This listening socket could receive data from multiple sources. If the listening socket receives back to back socket data, the application is expected to queue the data and process the data on a First come first serve bases.

Hence I created a synchronous socket to receive data. If the server receives data from 2 sources, it processes the data from source 1 and sends the completion status to source 1 and then takes the data from source 2,processes it and informs the status and this goes on. The socket is created on a thread so that it could receive and process data independently from the UI.

The application was meeting its objective as most of the communication was through sockets and people were not really using the UI for entering data.

Recently, as people started UI, i noticed a completely new issue. When someone tries to enters a data on to UI while the socket data is in process, it stops the socket data processing. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on the host, it resumes the processing of the socket data.

I could not identify my mistake here. Also, I looked over to the Backgroundworkder class but I am not sure if that would allow the sockets commands to be processed in a synchronous way.

Please treat me as a newbie as I am still learning and complex suggestions might be hard to digest.

```
public partial class frm_bot : Form
{

    public frm_bot()
    {
        StartServer();
    }

    private void frm_bot_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(OnClientConnect));
            myThread.IsBackground = true;
            myThread.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            showErrorMsg(ex.Message);
        }//catch  
    }

    public void StartServer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Net.IPAddress localIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(GetlocalIp());
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 8089);
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
    }

    private void OnClientConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener.Start();
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            clientSocket = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            _clientSocket = clientSocket;
            ReadCallback();
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not bind to Port 8089! Please close all Applications that uses Port 8089");
        }
    }
    public void ReadCallback()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_clientSocket.GetStream()))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_clientSocket.GetStream()))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                char[] c = null;

                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    c = new char[25];
                    sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                }

                string d = new string(c);
                string[] cmddata = d.Split('\0');
                string dataFromClient = cmddata[0];

                if (dataFromClient.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client sent empty string!");
                }
                else
                {
                    ProcessSocketData(dataFromClient);
                    sw.Write("Done");
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            OnClientConnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientConnect();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessSocketData(string sockdata)
    {
        try
        {
            // Socket data is processed here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception on ProcessSocketData: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong in so many levels. Could you please provide what are you trying to achieve? e.g. the meaning of `The application was meeting its objective`

Comment: [`StreamReader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx): "Reads a specified **maximum** of characters from the current stream ... (return value)  The number will be less than or equal to the count parameter". Considering that you *ignore* the return value, do you really think your code is close to correct?

Comment: @brainlesscoder The primary objective is that the application being able to process the socket data in a sequential manner in the order that it receives without interruptions even if someone is using the interface to send data to the other COM ports

Comment: You can't create, access or update UI elements from a non-UI thread. Fix that first and then see if you still have any errors.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am trying to understand something here. Does that mean that if I am trying to access anything on the UI side, the non-UI thread would be getting into a blocking state?

Comment: No, it means that you're corrupting state of the UI by accessing from a non-UI thread. The UI thread is then blocking because of the corrupted state.